# Product Image Zooming with multiple layered Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-plugins

**Scenario:**

- I have stacked (layered) images that represents various part of the image.
- Two there transparent png together makes a product. I am changing particular png images based on dropdown. So user can customize the product.

**Problem:**

Now what I want is to implement product zoom functionality into this. All jquery plugin I have found so far is based on single image.

How to I implement the image zoom functionality that doesn't take a single image to zoom it but perhaps the whole container of stacked images?

**[edit]**

**What I have tried so far:**

I have tried [Anything Zoomer](http://css-tricks.com/anythingzoomer-jquery-plugin/) jQuery Plugin but it didn't work. You can see it **[here](http://kowsky.projekt.dealux.de/product/light-metal-walking-sticks-adjustable/)**. The code I used to implement is below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="image-canvas">
        <div class="small">
            <div data-filter="filter1" class="layer layer1"><img alt="smaller" src="http://kowsky.projekt.dealux.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/rohr-66dddd-266x400.png"></div>
            <div data-filter="filter2" class="layer layer2"><img alt="smaller" src="http://kowsky.projekt.dealux.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ergo-griff-000000-266x400.png">/div>
        </div>

        <div class="large">
            <div data-filter="filter1" class="layer layer1"><img alt="larger" src="http://kowsky.projekt.dealux.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/rohr-66dddd.png"></div>
            <div data-filter="filter2" class="layer layer2"><img alt="larger" src="http://kowsky.projekt.dealux.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ergo-griff-000000.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#image-canvas").anythingZoomer({
         smallArea   : 'small',
         largeArea   : 'large',
});
```

**Note:**

Transparent PNG's are absolute positioned.

Comment: have u tried with Zoomooz plugins

Comment: @Somnath: didn't tried it but it doesn't look like that I want. Check my post edit.

Comment: **Possible** (not sure) alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193672/an-alternative-to-anythingzoomer/18197048#18197048

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [panzoom library](http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/).

Include it in your header and add a div with an id that you can later reference with the panzoom functions.

**HTML**

```
<div id="panzoom">
  <img src="http://kowsky.projekt.dealux.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/rohr-66dddd-266x400.png">
  <img src="http://kowsky.projekt.dealux.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/ergo-griff-000000-266x400.png">
</div>

<div>
  <button class="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
  <button class="zoom-out">Zoom Out</button>
  <input type="range" class="zoom-range">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#panzoom').panzoom({
  $zoomIn: $(".zoom-in"),
  $zoomOut: $(".zoom-out"),
  $zoomRange: $(".zoom-range")
});
```